# Interface to list in a static class

Tags: c#, interface

I have a list of types. I need to find the matching type in the list by it's name. And if such type exists should get it's instance. List of types is stored in a static class that plays role of global configuration and stores all the things configured for the app. 
What is the right way to show the interface for the List of types to the outside, so that I could easilly look for a type by name, get the type I need to and still don't put too much methods into static class and don't revel too much data.

I was thinking on putting some interface that will allow me to look for the type by name, like IConfigurationSearchable. Make Configuration return this interface and implement everything against it. Flexible, no pollution of Configurator interface. But I decided to ask on SO to make sure there's no better way to do this.

I have a static class that allows me to add some classes. Like this:

`configuration.Add(new Test());
 configuration.Add(new AnotherTest());
 configuration.Add(new SomeFancyName());`

I want an interface that will allow me to check is class with name Test contained in collection. Maybe later I will decide to check if class that starts with Test is inside the collection, etc. Also I wil need to get by name the class that contained there or list of classes contained there. So things can change and I'm not sure how to make the interface to my configurator, so that it would be possible to erform changes with less pain.

Comment: Please give a sort example demonstrating what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just to make sure, why isn't `IEnumerable<Type>` good enough? This is searchable with LINQ, and keeps almost all information to itself.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement IReadOnlyDictionary<string,object>.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the q, but if these are custom classes, you create an Attribute and have each class implement that Attribute.

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform some kind of dependency injection or service locator; perhaps something like Funq? http://funq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Updated the question. No, I know what is DI. The question is not how to decouple Interface and implementation or switch implementations or make everything via interface or not. The question is what interface is flexible enough to be used, or way to expose interface is flexible enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into a simple Dependency Injection container such as TinyIoC:
https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC

With this, you can register instances of types, such as:

```
// register Foo
container.Register<Foo>();
...
// later on, get this instance by using:
var instance = container.Resolve<Foo>();
```

or even better, register an interface and an implementation, and then later on in the code, just use the interface:

```
// register Foo as the concrete implementation of IFoo
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>();
...
// later on, get a concrete instance that implements the IFoo interface
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

This will give you the flexiblity to change the Foo implementation while any code that uses it will only be dependent on the IFoo interface.

Comment: The question is about the best interface between static configurator and classes that need to find out if type contained in the list by name. And as class is static, it\s not about how to wrap interfaces. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't want to answer my own question, but as number of answers is relatively low(1). I don't mind to mark as answer any good answer you post after my own.

I made an interface IGetTestable() and return it from my singleton configuration as a method.
So if anything changes in terms of implementation I will only need to change the implementation.

And the way I interact with my collection is not smashed around the configuration object and it's methods.